# Invalid Character in String with JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, eval

Can someone help me determine what the issue is with this string...

Visual Studio Escaped String

```
"({ID:[\"1\"],ElementID:[\"1\"],UserHashKey:[\"39f46b38-e4c5-4081-aba4-28158d271952\"],[new String(\"FirstName88\")]:[new String(\"Ryan\")],[new String(\"LastName89\")]:[new String(\"Leesh\")],[new String(\"Type90\")]:[new String(\"Dental\")],[new String(\"Test[\\\"\\\"]91\")]:[new String(\"Help Me\")],UserCreated:[\"rleesh@hotmail.com\"],Created:[\"9/23/2015\"],Updated:[\"9/23/2015\"]})"
```

Visual Studio Text Visualizer

```
({ID:["1"],ElementID:["1"],UserHashKey:["39f46b38-e4c5-4081-aba4-28158d271952"],[new String("FirstName88")]:[new String("Ryan")],[new String("LastName89")]:[new String("Leesh")],[new String("Type90")]:[new String("Dental")],[new String("Test[\"\"]91")]:[new String("Help Me")],UserCreated:["ryanleesh@hotmail.com"],Created:["9/23/2015"],Updated:["9/23/2015"]})
```

I receive the same error for both eval(str) and JSON.parse(str)

Invalid character

I know the issue comes from the following [\"\"], but I can't figure out how to manipulate it to pass the parsing engine.

Code is as follows:

```
String.prototype.toFieldDef = function () {
    var str = '({' + this + '})';
str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');

try {
    //str = JSON && JSON.parse(str) || $.parseJSON(str);
    str = eval(str);
} catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof SyntaxError) {
        try{
            str = eval('"'+str+'"')
        } catch (f) {
            if (f instanceof SyntaxError) {
                alert(f.message);
            }
        } 
    }
}

return str;
```

};

Comment: So, what does the JSON string look like when you receive it?

Comment: why are there outer `()` ? Is this being parsed from `jsonp` ? Escaped quotes shouldn't be an issue. Also concatenating string with `this` doesn't make sense

Comment: function is a extension. this contains a string from a hidden div in on the page. the string is being built from a controller and set up in the view (mvc).

Comment: @JonathanM, JSON doesn't compile correctly. Returns error invalid character.

Comment: @Ryan, I'm asking what the JSON string looks like *before* you try to compile it.

Comment: @JonathanM, when I break on the eval(str) statement in debug, the string  shows as the examples above. Hovering over the str variable shows the "Visual Studio Escaped String" as above and clicking the hour glass shows the "Visual Studio Text Visualizer" as above.

I believe the escaped version of the string str is being passed to the eval(str), but maybe this is where the issue actually is.

Comment: This question appears to have nothing to do with JSON. I see no JSON here.

Comment: @JonathanM, yes it does. The string above is in a JSON stringified format and needs to be converted to javascript objects using eval which runs JSON.parse()

Comment: @Ryan, no. It has segments like `[new String("Type90")]`. This is not legal JSON. Legal JSON is defined here: http://json.org/

Comment: @JonathanM, you only grabbed the first part of the statement. [new String("Type90")]:[new String("Dental")] is the complete statement. But you make a valid point here. Is the reason why it is not passing as JSON is because the string on the object declaration is wrappered with brackets. []

Comment: @JonathanM, ok so really trying to break this down, this is an issue where the special character is in the json key.  How do I reformat the JSON string to allow the following:

[new String("Test[\"\"]91")]:[new String("Help Me")]

where Test[""] is the JSON Key and "Help Me" is the value?

Comment: @Ryan, the problem is more than the brackets. JSON has NO type declarations, and it requires quotes around each property name. Did you look at the definition of JSON at the json.org site?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem that I see is that some of the object keys are specified to be arrays.  Consider:

```
js> x="{[new String(\"FirstName88\")]:[new String(\"Ryan\")]}";
js> eval(x)
typein:2: SyntaxError: invalid label:
typein:2: {[new String("FirstName88")]:[new String("Ryan")]}
typein:2: ...........................^
```

Replacing the square brackets with parentheses doesn't help, at least when using JavaScript-C or v8.  You'll either have to use a string literal, or programmatically construct (or reconstruct) the string to be evaluated.

Comment: Use the text visualizer string.  It has the escapes removed already.  The thing that makes this really confusing is that a copy/paste of the text visualizer string at the address below compiles correctly, but in the code pasted above, it does not.

http://www.infimum.dk/HTML/javascript/jstest5.html

Comment: can you try the whole "Visual Studio Text Visualizer" string in your eval(x) and see if you return the same error, "Invalid character".